# Linear regression on multidimensional dask arrays

Tags: dask

I am trying to perform linear regression on multidimensional A and b for arrays that are larger-than-memory. Using sklearn notation, my arrays have shapes:

```
A: (n_samples, n_features)
b: (n_samples, n_targets)
```

I have so far been using numpy arrays, and using [`sklearn.linear_model.ridge_regression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ridge_regression.html).

Now I am swapping to dask, and need to find something equivalent. I've tried passing the dask arrays to [`ridge_regression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ridge_regression.html), but I observe that I run out of memory when doing so. I've looked at dask_ml, but their [`LinearRegression`](https://ml.dask.org/modules/generated/dask_ml.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#dask_ml.linear_model.LinearRegression) model only takes 1D-arrays b/y with shape (n_samples), and requires the data to be chunked correctly, which I am not sure how to do. I can use a standard matrix inversion approach, but then I risk singular matrix errors.

A small worked example, which shows how the ridge_regression method ends up with a numpy array, not a dask array:

```py
import sklearn.linear_model

X = da.random.random((1024, 30))
y = da.random.random((1024, 10000))
fit = sklearn.linear_model.ridge_regression(X, y, alpha=0.0)
type(fit)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for models that can perform the above regression, but for large data?

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that `ridge_regression` is implemented on `dask`.

Comment: Agreed, although I am not sure how I would tell, other than just trying it.